# detect how many times color is seen

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

Hello ı am trying to something like,when camera see red color in first time there should be no reaction(there could be some delay for that but mine wasn't work,but when the second time see red color ı want to servo to work but when ı work that code its not happening what ı want it wait 5 second than work servo camera even see not

its my code

```
 
def ilkkirmizi():
  print("Kırmızı cisim görüldü su dökülmeyecek!..")
  

def donme():
  print("Kırmızı cisim görüldü su dökülüyor...")
  p.start(2.5) # Initialization
  p.ChangeDutyCycle(5)
  time.sleep(4)
  exit()


def red1():
  for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
      continue
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(goruntu,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
    genis = w
    ilkkirmizi()
    time.sleep(5)
    donme()

def red2():
  for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
      continue
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(goruntu,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
    genis = w
    donme()

red1()
red2()
```

Comment: you are expected to post a **minimal** reproducible example. you posted ~100 lines of code. I am sure most of those aren't needed to reproduce the issue. please reduce your code.

Comment: I updated a code,actually ı just want when the raspberrypi camera see red color the first time nothing should be happened just skip it but second time ı want to servo to work

Comment: basic programming: keep *state* (a variable), set state and *detect change* (comparison), and *when* the state changes, perform actions.

Comment: but which variable for that?

Comment: a new one. a boolean that says if you are *currently seeing* the desired color. if you are *not* in the state of seeing the color, but the current picture shows the color, you have a *change* in state, and you can react to it. when you are in the state of seeing the color, and the current picture shows the color, that means *no* change. and so on.

Comment: Please try to be more clear to explain your problem. Red color recognitions depends on many things. For instance, environment lightening will be a big problem. Please give more detail, or sample images